# Auto-crop image for grid layout

Tags: html, css

I have this template that I use to display product in a "grid" layout:

```
<div id="cols3-top"></div>
<div id="cols3" class="box" data-field="products">
    <div data-field="product" class="col">
    <h3><a href="#" data-field="title">Sample Product</a></h3>
        <p class="nom t-center"><a href="#"><img src="tmp/200x140.gif" alt="" data-field="imageurl"/></a></p>
    <div class="col-text">
        <p data-field="content">Product information</p> 
        <ul data-field="features" class="ul-01"></ul>
    </div> <!-- /col-text -->
    <div class="col-more"><a href="#">
            <img src="design/cols3-more.gif" alt="" data-field="morebutton"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>              
</div> <!-- /cols3 -->
<div id="cols3-bottom"></div>
```

However this is not optimized, since inf the image img size is not the same it would break the "grid" layout. How to optimize this layout such that it would "auto-crop" images to specific width and height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your images don't get larger than the cols they are in. For example:

```
#cols3 img{
    width:300px; /* width of #cols3 */
    height:auto;
}
```

Most probably you can also use `100%` instead of `300px`